# django not returning request response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am using this code to make an api which return the post request so i can test and modify them according to my needs.

I have tried two codes by searching on SO.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import json


@csrf_exempt
def some_view(request, username):
    json_data = json.dumps(request)
    return JsonResponse(json_data, safe=False)
```

This code give me the error of `is not JSON serializable`.

If i applied a list attribute to it. Like

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import json


@csrf_exempt
def some_view(request, username):
    json_data = json.dumps(list(request))
    return HttpResponse(json_data)
```

it did not give me an error but return the empty output.`[]`

Edit: if i tried to return `request.POST`. I got a empty array.

I am testing this api through `POSTMAN`.

Comment: A request object is complex and requires additional handling to be JSON serialized. You should try to return only parts of it like the post data at first.

Answer (score 2):

`request` is a [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) object - not the raw request body. You need to access that with `request.body`. You probably also want to use `JsonResponse` instead of `HttpResponse` if you want to return JSON via a Python object:

```
request_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))   # This assumes your request body is JSON
json_data = json.dumps(request_data)
return JsonResponse(json_data)
```

(I'm assuming that you will do a bit more that just returning the original request later on).

Comment: thank you for comment let me try this! yeah i have long way to process this request and linked this to scrapy and other stuff but for now i am making an api

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read `Request` object attributes, you can use `request.__dict__`.
This will return you serailizable object something like

```
{
    'FILES': < MultiValueDict: {} > ,
    'COOKIES': {},
    '_post_parse_error': False,
    'resolver_match': None,
    'GET': < QueryDict: {} > ,
    'META': {},
    'path_info': u '',
    'path': u '',
    'POST': < QueryDict: {} > ,
    'method': None
}
```

You may need to iterate over and read `__dict__` attributes of nested objects too, such as `'GET': <QueryDict: {}>`, `'POST': <QueryDict: {}>`.

Comment: how i will get this in the request ?? and is i try to send like this `return JsonResponse(request.__dict__)` it is still giving me the error of serialize.

Comment: You need to iterate over & read `__dict__` of nested attributes as well, like `FILES`, 'POST', etc.  Any object which is not serializable will cause error.

Comment: cant i just return the request object?

Comment: No, object needs to be serializable.

Comment: actually i dont want to make a loop overthere i just want to send a whole object